# DD-WRT firmware version and release schedule

Tags: router, dd-wrt, dnsmasq

The DD-WRT website claims that the [recent vulnerabilities in DNSMASQ have been fixed](http://svn.dd-wrt.com/ticket/5987) in release r33430, however the latest betas on the website are older then this - release r33413 from 27 Sept (and the release for my router from the router database page is even more ancient, being a v24 version).   I'm very keen to patch my routers.

Can anyone advise -

1. Is there any way I can get my hands on the latest release for an
   Asus RT-AC68U ?
2. What is the expected lag time between a change being made and a release being downloadable ?
3. How safe is it to use a v30 BETA release for the RT-AC68U, when the "supported by" field in the router database states V24PreSP2
   [Beta] Build: 23940 as the only option, but there is an
   asus-rt-ac68u firmware under Downlads/betas/2017/09-27-2017-r33413
   as well ?

Comment: You would have to build and test it yourself